# For Loop for printing method

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods

Having and issue creating a `for` loop to print the code I already have. 
Could you please help the best you can.

```
public class Lab2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int [] nums = {10,20,30,40};
    int k = 1;

}

    public static void rotate(int[] nums , int k  ) {
        if(k > nums.length) 
            k=k%nums.length;

        int[] result = new int[nums.length];

        for(int i=0; i < k; i++){
            result[i] = nums[nums.length-k+i];
        }

        int j=0;
        for(int i=k; i<nums.length; i++){
            result[i] = nums[j];
            j++;
        }



        }

    }
```

Comment: You forgot to call your method `rotate` from your `main` method.

Comment: Also you should return your `int[] result` from `rotate`

Comment: The program isn't finished thats why im asking for help

Answer (score 1):

By printing your code you mean printing the output of your method?
As the comments state you should return an array from your `rotate(int[] nums, int k)` method and then change your main-method:

```
import java.utils.Arrays;
public class Lab2{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int [] nums = {10,20,30,40};
    int k = 4; //whatever
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rotate(nums, i)));
    }
}
 public static int[] rotate(int[] nums , int k  ) {
    if(k > nums.length){
        k=k%nums.length;
    }

    int[] result = new int[nums.length];

    for(int i=0; i < num.length; i++){
        if((i+k) < num.length){
            result[i+k] = nums[i];
        }else{
            result[(i+k)-nums.length] = nums[i]
        }
    }
    return result;
 }
 }
```

**EDIT:** The code now contains necessary import and `rotate` with return-type (and should actually rotate the array)

Comment: I believe that Arrays.toString() would return the whole array. So you are printing the array `k` times. In addition to this, he would need to import java.utils.Arrays.

Comment: I think I wrote that `rotate`should return an array and if this adjustment is done my code would print the array `k` times with different rotations.

Comment: Yes sir, it would. I didn't read so good the first time. But still needs that import.

Comment: Yes i trying to print the new rotated array.

Comment: @Cotypiechocki If you follow what recke96 said above, you will be able to print a rotated array k times. If you are interested in only one print, removing the loop would help you there. But other than that, what was said above will fix your problem.

Comment: i actually changed a few things. num goes to nums and k=1 and then the output goes from i to k